# Perl Client to Java Server

Tags: java, perl

I'm trying to write a perl client program to connect to a Java server application (JDuplicate).  I see that the java server uses The DataInput.readUTF and DataInput.writeUTF methods, which the JDuplicate website lists as "Java's modified UTF-8 protocol".

My test program is pretty simple, i'm trying to send client type data, which should invoke a response from the sever, however it just times out:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Encode;
use IO::Socket;

my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  Proto => 'tcp',
  PeerAddr => 'localhost',
  PeerPort => '10421'
) or die "Cannot connect to server\n";

$|++;

$remote->send(encode_utf8("CLIENTTYPE|JDSC#0.5.9#0.2"));
while (<$remote>) {
  print $_,"\n";
}
close($remote);

exit(0);
```

I've tried $remote->send(pack("U","..."));, I've tried "use utf8;", I've tried binmode($remote, ":utf8"), and I've tried sending just plain ASCII text, nothing ever gets responded to.

I can see the data being sent with tcpdump, all in one packet, but the server itself does nothing with it (other then ack the packet).

Is there something additional i need to do to satisfy the "modified" utf implementation of Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the [protocol](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) correctly:

> First, the total number of bytes needed to represent all the characters of `s` is calculated. If this number is larger than 65535, then a `UTFDataFormatException` is thrown. Otherwise, this length is written to the output stream in exactly the manner of the [`writeShort`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeShort(int)) method; after this, the one-, two-, or three-byte representation of each character in the string `s` is written.

As indicated in the docs for `writeShort`, it sends a 16-bit quantity in network order.

In Perl, that resembles

```
sub sendmsg {
  my($s,$msg) = @_;

  die "message too long" if length($msg) > 0xffff;

  my $sent = $s->send(
    pack(n => (length($msg) & 0xffff)) .
    $msg
  );

  die "send: $!"    unless defined $sent;
  die "short write" unless $sent == length($msg) + 2;
}

sub readmsg {
  my($s) = @_;
  my $buf;
  my $nread;

  $nread = $s->read($buf, 2);
  die "read: $!"   unless defined $nread;
  die "short read" unless $nread == 2;

  my $len = unpack n => $buf;

  $nread = $s->read($buf, $len);
  die "read: $!"   unless defined $nread;
  die "short read" unless $nread == $len;

  $buf;
}
```

Although the code above doesn't perform modified UTF encoding, it elicits a response:

```
my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  Proto => 'tcp',
  PeerAddr => 'localhost',
  PeerPort => '10421'
) or die "Cannot connect to server: $@\n";

my $msg = "CLIENTTYPE|JDSC#0.5.9#0.2";

sendmsg $remote, $msg;

my $buf = readmsg $remote;
print "[$buf]\n";
```

Output:

```
[SERVERTYPE|JDuplicate#0.5.9 beta (build 584)#0.2]
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm now able to communicate back and forth as expected.  Thank  you.

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to the main part of your question, but I thought I would explain what the "Java's modified UTF-8" that the API expects is; it's UTF-8, except with UTF-16 surrogate pairs encoded as their own codepoints, instead of having the characters *represented* by the pairs encoded directly in UTF-8. For instance, take the character `U+1D11E MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF`.

- In UTF-8 it's encoded as the four bytes `F0 9D 84 9E`.
- In UTF-16, because it's beyond `U+FFFF`, it's encoded using the surrogate pair `0xD834 0xDD1E`.
- In "modified UTF-8", it's given the UTF-8 encoding of the surrogate pair codepoints: that is, you encode `"\uD834\uDD1E"` into UTF-8, giving `ED A0 B4 ED B4 9E`, which happens to be fully six bytes long.

When using this format, Java will also encode any embedded nulls using the illegal overlong form `C0 80` instead of encoding them as nulls, ensuring that there are never any embedded nulls in a "modified UTF-8" string.

If you're not sending any characters outside of the BMP or any nulls, though, there's no difference from the real thing ;)

Here's some [documentation courtesy of Sun](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html).